# Python how to combine a string and list to a tuple

Tags: python, types, tuples

I have a string and a list

```
a=100
b=["abc","def"]
```

How do I combine these to a tuple, that looks like (abc, 100), (def, 100)? I tried

```
>>> for i in file:
...   tuple(file, uid)
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
TypeError: tuple() takes at most 1 argument (2 given)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a=100
b=["abc","def"]

print [(i,a) for i in b]
```

You can do this through simple `list comprehension`

Answer (score 0):

as the traceback said, `tuple` takes 1 argument, in your code, just change `tuple(file, uid)` to `tuple([file, uid])`. That is to say, `tuple` takes one argument which is iterable